# Can we express $CX_{2,1}CX_{1,2}$ as single standard 2-qubits gate?

Tags: gate-synthesis

[image]

I'd like to know if the above circuit can be synthesised as any single standard 2-qubit gate -- e.g. an Ising gate.

Eventually, other 1-qubit correcting gates.

EDIT: with standard I mean any gate that has practical implication. Especially when this can be directly implemented on hardware.

Comment: Could you maybe specify what are "standard 2-qubit gates"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this gate combination is equivalent to a CNOT followed by a SWAP:
[image]

In stim this gate is correspondingly called [`CXSWAP`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SWAPCX) (and its inverse is called [`SWAPCX`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SWAPCX)):

> **SWAPCX**
>
> A combination SWAP-then-CX gate.
> This gate is kak-equivalent to the iswap gate, but preserves X/Z noise bias.
>
> Stabilizer Generators:
>
> ```
> X_ -> _X
> Z_ -> ZZ
> _X -> XX
> _Z -> Z_
> ```
>
> Unitary Matrix (little endian):
>
> ```
> [+1  ,     ,     ,     ]
> [    ,     ,     , +1  ]
> [    , +1  ,     ,     ]
> [    ,     , +1  ,     ]
> ```
>
> Decomposition (into H, S, CX, M, R):
>
> ```
> # The following circuit is equivalent (up to global phase) to `SWAPCX 0 1`
> CNOT 0 1
> CNOT 1 0
> ```

```
import stim
c = stim.Circuit("CXSWAP 0 1")
c.diagram(type='timeline-svg')
```

> [image]

We used CXSWAP gate in the paper ["Relaxing Hardware Requirements for Surface Code Circuits using Time-dynamics"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.02192), to explain iswap-based surface code circuits. A CXSWAP is the same as an iswap gate, up to single qubit rotations before and afterwards, but has the nice property that it doesn't mix the X and Z bases which makes constructions easier to explain and diagram:

> [image]